# Convertir fecha UTC con un Offset a hora local en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

¿Saben por que al momento de convertir una fecha de tipo DatetimeOffset SQL Server suma las horas en vez de restarlas?.

Lo que estoy tratando de realizar es convertir la fecha de UTCDATETIME a una fecha local, pero no esta funcionado.

Tengo el siguiente query que me genera el siguiente resultado:

```
 SELECT 
     GETUTCDATE() AS CURRENT_DATE_UTC, 
     GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'CENTRAL STANDARD TIME (MEXICO)' AS DATE_OFFSET,
     CONVERT(DATETIME,GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'CENTRAL STANDARD TIME (MEXICO)',1) 
     AS CONVERT_TO_TIME_ZONE
    FROM BAT_BALANCE_PAYMENT;
```

[image: Resultado de query]

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto: Para que tome el valor correctamente, se debe de castear la fecha a convertir a el tipo de dato DATETIMEOFFSET

```
SELECT 
 GETUTCDATE() AS CURRENT_DATE_UTC, 
 GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'CENTRAL STANDARD TIME (MEXICO)' AS DATE_OFFSET,
 CAST(CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATETIMEOFFSET) AT TIME ZONE 'CENTRAL STANDARD TIME (MEXICO)' AS DATETIME) 
 AS CONVERT_TO_TIME_ZONE
FROM BAT_BALANCE_PAYMENT;
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]